# SQL jdbc query support required

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

There is a schema Flight(flightnumber, processed int)
pilot(pilot_number, pilot_name)

To assign a pilot to the flight I first scan the flight table and for each flight number I did a query(inside method called Assignment(Flight flight).

```
public void select(){
      Flight flight = new flight();
      query = “select * from flight”;
then
//for each flight do some query
public void Assignment(Flight flight){
     //query with flightnumber = flight.flightnumber
}
```

Now the requirement has changed. A new column processed is added to Flight table.
I have to use Assignment() (now it has no arguments) and find the first unprocessed flight in flights to do some query and then set processed value to 1.

database sql .. java jdbc
How do I do this? Thank you for reading my question. Hope I was clear.

Comment: Please show us sample data for the tables you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle this

We can have filter criteria in the select statement

```
SELECT * FROM flight
WHERE is_processed =0 AND rownum=1 
//returns only one record with the status of `is_processed` as 0
```

After the assignment update the `is_processed` value to 1 for the returned flight details. //do above actions under same transaction

Other way is to combine these steps in a stored-procedure and call the procedure from your java code

Let me know if I misunderstood your question

Comment: Thank you for your response.